# Opcional carrinho de compra

Tags: php, array

Positivo adicionou / Negativo retirou

```
([1] => 3 [6] => -2 )
```

Seguinte o cliente pode alterar todas configurações do lanche contem uma quantidade padrão (receita)

*ele pode retirar 2x e pode adicionar alface 1x 2x 3x*

no caso ele **adiciono 3x** e **retirou 2x**

entao o sistema tem que fazer uma **subistituição 1 bife por 1 alface e adicional de 1 alface**, entao o sistema tem que ter adicional/retirada/substituição... ao meu ver sempre vai acontecer ou **substitui e adiciona** ou **substitui e retira** /// ou apenas **subistitui**

lembrando que e tudo dinamico pode acontecer essa possibilidades varias vezes

```
-+ Bacon por Alfance = R1,00
 + Alfance = R$ 0,50
-+ 2x Bacon por Alfance = R2,00
 + Alfance = R$ 0,50
```

aqui tem uma demonstração http://jsfiddle.net/qtx8jrLy de como seria a parte do cliente o que ele pode fazer...

os que ja vem marcado e a receita padrao do produto... que tbm pode ser alterada...

consegui fazer ate

```
**o problema esta aki como interpretar esse array**    
(
    [1] => 3  // [id_produto] => quantidade
    [6] => -2 // [id_produto] => quantidade
    )
fazer-lo virar 
    -+ 2x Bacon por Alfance = R2,00
     + Alfance = R$ 0,50


**as os possivel acontecimentos para esse array** 

    -+ 2x Bacon por Alfance = R2,00
     + Alfance = R$ 0,50

    -+ Bacon por Alfance = R1,00
     - Alfance = R$ 0,50

    -+ 2x Bacon por Alfance = R1,00
```

***http://www.amburgueria.com.br/carrinhoOO/ coloquei o sistema online***

Comment: Não percebi qual é o problema.

Comment: como fazer a leitura desse array... eu to garrado nele não consegui interpretá-lo

Comment: Talvez você deva incluir um campo _hidden_ com o valor total dos produtos, então ao adicionar ou remover um item do lanche, você vai fazendo a gestão de acordo com o "saldo" do cliente.
E no Array trazer mais informações como `[id] = {[quantidade] = 3, [valor] = [2.00], [qtd_padrao] = 2}`

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema começa no cliente e é transportado para o servidor. Para começar a resolver, troque as checkbox por select e crie um formulário pedido

```
<form name="pedido">
<label >Bife (adicione ou retire quantidade)</label>
<select name="bife">
<option value="-3">retirar 3 porções</option>
<option value="-2">retirar 2 porções</option>
<option value="-1">retirar 1 porções</option>
<option value="0">Não quero este ingrediente</option>
<option value="1">acrescentar 1 porções</option>
<option value="2">acrescentar 2 porções</option>
<option value="3">acrescentar 3 porções</option>
</select>

<label >Alface (adicione ou retire quantidade)</label>
<select name="alface">
<option value="-3">retirar 3 porções</option>
<option value="-2">retirar 2 porções</option>
<option value="-1">retirar 1 porções</option>
<option value="0">Não quero este ingrediente</option>
<option value="1">acrescentar 3 porções</option>
<option value="2">acrescentar 3 porções</option>
<option value="3">acrescentar 3 porções</option>
</select>

<label >Bacon (adicione ou retire quantidade)</label>
<select name="bacon">
<option value="-3">retirar 3 porções</option>
<option value="-2">retirar 2 porções</option>
<option value="-1">retirar 1 porções</option>
<option value="0">Não quero este ingrediente</option>
<option value="1">acrescentar 3 porções</option>
<option value="2">acrescentar 3 porções</option>
<option value="3">acrescentar 3 porções</option>
</select>
</form>
```

para receber no servidor algo como isto:

```
$_POST["bife"] = 1;
$_POST["bacon"] = -2;
$_POST["alface"] = 0;


$receita["bife"] = 1;
$receita["bacon"] = 3;
$receita["alface"] = 5;

$preço["bife"] = 10;
$preço["bacon"] = 2;
$preço["alface"] = 1;




$pedido["bife"] = ($_POST["bife"]) ? ($receita["bife"]+$_POST["bife"]) * $preço["bife"]   : 0;
$pedido["bacon"] = ($_POST["bacon"]) ? ($receita["bacon"]+$_POST["bacon"]) * $preço["bacon"] : 0 ;
$pedido["alface"] = ($_POST["alface"]) ? ($receita["alface"]+$_POST["alface"]) * $preço["alface"] : 0;

$valor-do-pedido = $pedido["bife"] + $pedido["bacon"] + $pedido["alface"];
```

Penso que assim, torna menos confuso o pedido para o utilizador uma vez que o informa claramente o que espera que ele faça, e torna o pedido mais fácil de processar.

Claro que este código é extremamente simples.

Comment: mais chega assim la, msm com os checkbox ai subitraio o array_cliente pelo array_receita... ai ele devolve [1] => 3 / [6] = -2 // que seria 3 alface adiciona e 2 bife retirados... acaba nao precisando de select

Comment: o lance e interpretar esse array [1] = 3 / [6] = -2 //// -+ Bacon por Alfance = R1,00
 + Alfance = R$ 0,50
-+ 2x Bacon por Alfance = R2,00
 + Alfance = R$ 0,50

Comment: Tanto chega que não consegue resolver o problema.Esta é a segunda vez que coloca a questão. Quanto mais complicar uma situação, mais aumenta o risco de erros. Mas é uma opção sua. Se fosse um problema meu resolveria assim. Simples e direto. Mas é apenas uma sugestão, está no seu direito aceitar.

Comment: manuel repara bem, o que esta de diferente e checkbox para select... essa opção sua daria mesma coisa... [alface] => 3 [bacon] = -2 / chego no msm caminho / no msm array fico no 3 positivo e 2 negativo do msm jeito

Comment: e onde está a sua tabela de preços? a sua tabela com o custo de cada substituição?

Comment: em uma db vou fazer a busca deles com a [$id] => quantidade

Comment: mas tem um preço fixo para cada ingrediente ou depende da substituição que o cliente faça? Ou seja, 1 porção de alface custa sempre 0,50 ou se for para substituir o bacon custa 0,25 e se for para substituir o bife custa o,75?

Comment: Se for o ultimo caso, então tem que pedir ao cliente para dizer que substituições quer fazer, porque ser reduzir a alface e o bacon e aumentar o bife, não sabe se ele quer substituir pelo bacon ou pela alface.

Comment: então o valor e fixo.. eu subtraio: bacon 2.00 / alface 1.00 = -1,00 esses -1.00 jogo no valor total do lanche

Comment: Fiz uma edição, para calcular o preço do pedido.

Comment: e verdade ai garro ne... qual ele quer retirar... vc ve alguma solução pra isso?

Comment: ou terei que fazer uma pagina pra adiciona e pra remover e outra para substituir

Comment: quando ele quiser retirar fica zero. Vc pode escrever "Não quero este ingrediente". Veja a alteração

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei bem como está o seu projeto, nem o motivo do uso de *checkbox* entre outras modelagens, também não sei se está de fácil alteração ou não.

Mas eu tomei a liberdade de fazer um código que hospedei no JSFiddle de como tu poderia fazer esse teu projeto.

**[Link para o código](http://fiddle.jshell.net/at7kgnr3/)**

**[Link para o código com PHP](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xbvu-w9a4)**

Daí um exemplo como tu pode receber os dados enviados:

```
<?php 

   if (isset($_POST['produto'])){
      $pedido = '';

      foreach ($_POST['produto'] as $id => $dados) {
         if ($dados['qtd'] <= 0) continue;
         $pedido .= "ID: {$id} <br>QTD: {$dados['qtd']}<br><br>";
      }
      echo $pedido.'<hr><br>';
   }

?>
```

Ai é só buscar no banco pelo ID do item o valor, multiplicar pela quantidade informada e etc.

Comment: sim, e quase isso @KaduAmaral , mais como ele vai identificar se e adicional retirada ou substituição?
adicionais sao +o- 50 opção // 
retirada sao os ingredientes padrao 
// e substituição e caso ele retire um ingrediente e adiciona outro.. o problema que o sistema nao consegue identificar esse exempo: addicionei bacon 2x agora quero tirar 2x batata palha 1x alface 1x ovo com qual desses 3 via fazer a substituição? quero tirar 1x batata e 1x alface

Comment: http://www.amburgueria.com.br/carrinhoOO/ da uma olhada ai o sistema online

Comment: Pois então, nesse exemplo ai que eu dei, se o cara quer remover um item ele deixa como 0, ou então tu pode colocar um botãozinho ao lado para excluir a linha, e se ele quer adicionar, tem ali as opções adicionais e também a opção para alterar a quantidade. E o produto deve ser feito pelos dados enviados pelo formulário.

Comment: sim eu vi isso, e o substituir?

Comment: Tu precisa limitar o saldo, para que o valor do lanche não passe do valor padrão? E esse substituir, é o usuário que vai escolher pelo que vai substituir? Se for assim isso é um buraco a mais que você está cavando, pois se o usuário puder remover um item e adicionar outro, juntando os dois já seria a substituição.

Comment: entao isso msm junta remover e adicionar ai vira o substituir... mais o problema e que se ele remover 2 itens exemplo batata e bacon e adicionar queijo como vai saber por qual ele quer subistituir? a nao ser que usa uma inteligencia artificial ver qual dos remover e mais caro e trocar por ele? seria a solução?

Comment: entao kadu preciso de ler esse array aki o ([1] => 3 [6] => -2 ) [id]=>quantidade positivo e addicionar / negativo e remover... e uma AI pra substituir que confere esse array o subistituir e pelo preço que busco no sql... ai seta pq o cara pd fazer uma bagunça nesses checkbox vc viu http://www.amburgueria.com.br/carrinhoOO/ ? e nesse caso ai e 2 subistituir e um adicional

Comment: Qual a necessidade de saber por qual substituir? Eu acho que você está complicando a situação.

Comment: pois bacon e 2.00 alface e 1.00 file migon 6.00 // 2 bacon = 4 -* 2 alface = 2 se fosse com o maior o cliente so iria pagar um adicional de 2 reais

Comment: É mais fácil fazer o controle pelo preço do produto, como no [código que eu dei de exemplo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/at7kgnr3/), cada item tem um valor individual, e o valor total do lanche é gerado de acordo com a quantidade de cada item.

Comment: mais e a mesma coisa... se eu decrementa la o alface e o catupiry e 1x de bacon e adicionar +2 bife como ele vai fazer?

Comment: ([1] => 3 [6] => -2 [2] => -2)
// [id_produto] => quantidade

entao ex:
+ Alface 3x
- Bacon 2x
- Cheddar 2x

ele tem que fazer um subistituir... comparar o valor do [6] e [2] e fazer a troca com ele

resposta:

+ 2x Bacon - Alface
+ 1x Alface
- 2x Cheddar

Comment: Cara, sinto muito se não compreendi o propósito da sua aplicação. Mas nesse modelo de vendas que você apresentou, que substitui os itens do lanche, eu faria o **valor do lanche em cima do valor e quantidade de cada item**. Mostraria uma "receita padrão" para o usuário e deixaria que ele modificasse, então ele enviava essa modificação e eu salvaria o pedido dele no banco de dados, `pedidos(id, usuario); itens_pedidos(pedidoID, itemID, quantidade); itens(id, nome, valor)`.